# android gradle build error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 34.319 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: it is like your 65k method reach limit .. try to do multidex unable true in your gradle. for reference read this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

**If still getting error then you have to use give multidex support**

just add following gradle dependencies

```
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

then create  application class like this

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}}
```

and in  app gradle defaultConfig section add

```
   multiDexEnabled true
```

and last thing in manifest file add application class:

```
   android:name=".application.ApplicationClass"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your App **Build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "at.navigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"



        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Just Add **multiDexEnabled true** no need more code to solve this problem